# quick method count number of overlap intervals in an array of interval?

Tags: data-structures

OK, this is a question I got for my advance algorithm class. I already turned in my solution once but got rejected by my instructor due to efficiency issue, in other words, I already made the efforts on my part but could not get it even after his hint, so please be gentle. I will give his hint below

Given an array of intervals with both start point and end point, find the number of other intervals fall within it for each interval.  number of intervals is less than 10^9 and their ids are distinct. start and end are less than 10^18, the input files don't contain duplicate number for start and end.  All the numbers above are integers

the hint is: considering a data structure with buckets. The algorithm should be faster than O(n^2)

```
sample input and output

input:
5   %% number of intervals
2 100 200    %% id, start,end. all lines below follows this
3 110 190
4 105 145
1 90 150
5 102 198

output:
3 0
4 0
1 1
5 2
2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are pretty big so O(N log N) might be a little to much but here's an idea.

First things first normalize the values, that means turning them smaller while keepinging the same ordering. In your example the normalize would be

```
 90 100 102 105 110 145 150 190 198 200
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10
```

So you're new intervals are:

```
5
2 2 10
3 5 8
4 4 6
1 1 7
5 3 9
```

Now the edges of the intervals are in the range of [1, 2N].

Now sort the intervals by their end:

```
5
4 4 6
1 1 7
3 5 8
5 3 9
2 2 10
```

When you reach an interval you can say that all the intervals that start before it and have not been encountered yet should have their answer increased by one. This can be done with a SegmentTree.

What you do when you get an interval [x, y] you increase all values in the range [1, x - 1] by 1 and then compute its answer as the value at x in the segment tree. That's just addition on an interval and query on a point, a common segment tree problem.

I don't really think you can solve this problem with less than O(N log N) time and O(N) memory, so this solution should be the asymptotically best solution in both time and space.